# Cisco 3850 not saving port config

Tags: cisco, switching

I have a 3850 and whenever it reboots it loses its config. Power went out for a second today and it lost its port config. Weird thing is - it keeps the vlans. I have gone through this three times. I write the memory every single time and it says okay.

Can someone end my misery please?

Loses everything but vlans. Loses hostname, ip, ports

Comment: The vlan.dat file is stored in non-volatile memory.

Comment: VLANs are stored in their own database apart from the rest of the config. Have you verified your boot parameters and your register value?  Please post a full sanitized startup config (not running config, since that’s part of the issue) as well as a `show version` output.

Comment: The vlan.dat file is stored in non-volatile memory. Correct. I mention that so people know where the problem is.

Comment: @UneRoue You still haven’t supplied us with the requested info.

Comment: Life happens. Will get the startup config later and post again since this was closed short. I didn't know I only had 30 minutes after a mod edits your question to fix it. Thanks.